# Entities disappears when Platform reboots

Tags: fiware-orion

We have a problem with entities in OrionCB. Each time platform testbed is out of service, entities we have created before, disappears.

[root@orioncb ~]# curl localhost:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/finesce_meteo -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' | xmllint --format -
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
-:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

This is an exmaple of the output when we are trying to list "finesce_meteo" entity.

Regards,
Ismael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information in your question I cannot be sure (or not sure) that the entities have disapeared. The information in your questions lead to a different problem.

Note the `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host` message. That means that the client cannot reach the port 1026 of the host. The most probable causes of this problem are:

- Orion Context Broker is not started in that host
- Orion Context Broker is started in that host, but in a port different that 1026
- Something in the host (e.g a firewall or security group) is blocking the incoming connection
- Something in the client (e.g a firewall) is blocking the outcoming connection
- There is some other network issue is causing the connection problem.

Comment: Ok thanks. The problem was OrionCB is not started. We started after reboot, but it stops again by before we trying to list entities.